# How to return html on Gin?

Tags: html, go, go-gin

I'm trying to render a HTML that's already on a string instead of rendering a template on Gin framework.

The `c.HTML` function on `GET("/")` function expects a template to be rendered.

But on `POST("/markdown")` I've rendered that HTML on a string already.

**How can I return it on Gin?**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/russross/blackfriday"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(gin.Logger())
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*.tmpl.html")

    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.tmpl.html", nil)
    })

    router.POST("/markdown", func(c *gin.Context) {
        body := c.PostForm("body")
        log.Println(body)
        markdown := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(c.PostForm("body")))
        log.Println(markdown)
        // TODO: render markdown content on return
    })

    router.Run(":5000")
}
```

Comment: You can display markdown contents in html template

Comment: Ok @Bhavanna, But I'm trying to implement the examples from a book "Building web apps with Go"

Comment: What you want to do on post request? What output you are expecting?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can return the processed markdown byte array as a `RAW Data` and set content-type as `text/html; charset=utf-8`

This is how it may look like

```
router.POST("/markdown", func(c *gin.Context) {
        body, ok := c.GetPostForm("body")
        if !ok {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "badrequest")
            return
        }
        markdown := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(body))
        c.Data(http.StatusOK, "text/html; charset=utf-8", markdown)
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use constants for content types:

```golang
const (
    ContentTypeBinary = "application/octet-stream"
    ContentTypeForm   = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ContentTypeJSON   = "application/json"
    ContentTypeHTML   = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    ContentTypeText   = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
)
```

```golang
c.Data(http.StatusOK, ContentTypeHTML, []byte("<html></html>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the output of `blackfriday.MarkdownCommon()` to `template.HTML` like:

```
markdown := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(c.PostForm("body")))
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "markdown.html", gin.H {
    "markdown": template.HTML(markdown),
})
```